# Bash linux, Hour, Minutes and Seconds of a JPG Image

Tags: linux, bash, image

I am trying to get the complete date of an image in JPG format. The format I want to get is `14:25:38` (Hour:Minutes:Seconds).

I tried with the commands:

```
$ stat -c %y DSC_0002.JPG | sed 's/^\([0-9\-]*\).*/\1/'
=> 2017-05-19  -Not that way

$ file DSC_0002.JPG
=> DSC_0002.JPG: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=11, manufacturer=NIKON CORPORATION, model=NIKON D5200, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=180, yresolution=188, resolutionunit=2, software=Ver.1.01 , datetime=2017:05:19 13:30:34, GPS-Data], baseline, precision 8, 6000x4000, frames 3
```

This last (`file DSC_0002.JPG`) command displays `datetime=2017:05:19 13:30:34`, but I need to get only `13:30:34`

*Preferably without using add-ons or programs external to Linux bash.*

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Which date do you need?  JPEG images can have several datestamps - such as `DateTimeCaptured` and `DateTimeDigitized` - if they have an EXIF section (and you'll need `jhead` or `exiftool` to read them - don't attempt it in pure Bash!).

Comment: Toby Speight, but what about: identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]" image.jpg

Comment: ... or use `exiftool '-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal /path/to/myphotos` to set dates on all files based on exif time info. Once done, you could get files infos with `stat -c %y file.jpg`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, *pure bash* is possible too! Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44364445/1765658) (you've been cited;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## My 2 cents...

As *exif* is a big part of my job and because I already spent a lot of time building my own scripts, time is comming to make a little bench.

### Getting result of `jhead` using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

This use `jhead` because it's my prefered. See further to know why...

```
DateTime=$(jhead -nofinfo DSC_0002.JPG)
DateTime=${DateTime#*Date/Time*: }
DateTime=${DateTime%%$'\n'*}
```

This is the quickest way, (a lot quicker than using bash regex)!

```
echo $DateTime 
2011:02:27 14:53:32
```

### Different ways

Inquiring a *jpeg* file for knowing his date is possible by using at least 4 different tools:

1. `file` The *magic* `file` recognition command make some light inquiring on any file for determining is nature and print some more informations.

   ```
   file  DSC_0002.JPG 
   DSC_0002.JPG: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian,
   direntries=10, manufacturer=CANIKON, model=CANIKON AB12, orientation=upper-
   left, xresolution=168, yresolution=176, resolutionunit=2, software=Ver.1.00
   , datetime=2011:02:27 14:53:32], baseline, precision 8, 3872x2592, frames 3
   ```

   `file` print size, resolution and dateTime from a jpeg file.
2. `jhead` is a *jpeg's header* dedicated tool:

   ```
   jhead DSC_0002.JPG 
   File name    : DSC_0002.JPG
   File size    : 4940925 bytes
   File date    : 2011:02:27 14:53:32
   Camera make  : CANIKON
   Camera model : CANIKON AB12
   Date/Time    : 2011:02:27 14:53:32
   Resolution   : 3872 x 2592
   Flash used   : No
   Focal length : 55.0mm  (35mm equivalent: 82mm)
   Exposure time: 0.0080 s  (1/125)
   Aperture     : f/5.6
   ISO equiv.   : 180
   Whitebalance : Auto
   Metering Mode: pattern
   JPEG Quality : 97
   ```
3. `identify` is part of *ImageMagick* package wich is a kind of *all purpose* tool for bitmap images... (Due to some security bugs in past and overall perfomance, I'ts not my personal choice).

   ```
   identify DSC_0002.JPG 
   DSC_0002.JPG JPEG 3872x2592 3872x2592+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4.941MB 0.010u 0:00.020
   identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]\n" DSC_0002.JPG 
   2011:02:27 14:53:32
   ```
4. `exiftool` is a dedicated tool using `libimage`.

   ```
   exiftool DSC_0002.JPG
   ExifTool Version Number         : 9.74
   File Name                       : DSC_0002.JPG
   Directory                       : .
   File Size                       : 4.7 MB
   File Modification Date/Time     : 2011:02:27 14:53:32+01:00
   File Access Date/Time           : 2017:06:05 08:40:26+02:00
   File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2017:06:05 08:40:04+02:00
   File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
   File Type                       : JPEG
   MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
   Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
   ...
   Modify Date                     : 2011:02:27 14:53:32
   ...
   Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 8965 bytes, use -b option to extract)
   Circle Of Confusion             : 0.020 mm
   Depth Of Field                  : 15.07 m (8.58 - 23.65)
   Field Of View                   : 24.7 deg (5.50 m)
   Focal Length                    : 55.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 82.0 mm)
   Hyperfocal Distance             : 26.80 m
   Light Value                     : 11.1
   ```

   The default output of this is 185 lines length, I've dropped a lot.
5. **pure `bash`** As requested and because [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight) recommend [to not doing this](http://recommend%20to%20not%20doing%20this):

   ```
   FDate=;while IFS= read -d  $'\0'  -n 1024 raw;do
     [ "$raw" ] && \
     [ -z "${raw#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]}" ] &&
     FDate=$raw && break
   done <DSC_0002.JPG
   echo $FDate
   2011:02:27 14:53:32
   ```

   Ok, this a far away a perfect function: first date found in file is considered, regardless of fieldname.

### Little bench

As the goal is to extract *date time* part of exif infos, the bench would only do this.

```
time for i in {1..100};do ... done >/dev/null
export TIMEFORMAT="R:%4R u:%4U s:%4S"
```

Like this (from quicker to slower):

```
# quicker: jhead
time for i in {1..100};do jhead DSC_0002.JPG ;done >/dev/null
R:0.115  u:0.000  s:0.028

# 2nd: file
time for i in {1..100};do file DSC_0002.JPG; done >/dev/null
R:0.226  u:0.000  s:0.044

# 3nd: pure bash
time for i in {1..100};do 
    while IFS= read -d  $'\0' -n 1024 raw ;do
        [ "$raw" ] && 
        [ -z "${raw#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]}" ] &&
         ftim=$raw && break
      done <DSC_0002.JPG
   done >/dev/null
R:0.393  u:0.380  s:0.012

# 4nd: best dedicated: exiftool
time for i in {1..100};do exiftool -time:CreateDate DSC_0002.JPG ;done >/dev/null
R:14.921  u:13.064  s:0.956

# slower: imagemagick's identify
time for i in {1..100};do identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]\n" DSC_0002.JPG ;done >/dev/null
R:21.609  u:15.712  s:5.060
```

Sorry, I agree with [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight): Doing this in *pure bash* is a not so good idea!

### Setting file date

Doing date manipulation is very easy under pure bash, but working on file date. For this, I asked my system to set all photos files datetime to creation date found in exif.

For this, `exiftool` offer a specific syntax:

```
exiftool '-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal /path/to/myphotos
```

and `jhead` too:

```
jhead -q -ft /path/to/myphotos/*.JPG
```

This will set all creation file date based on creation date in exif infos. Once done, you could use standard tools for filesystem inquiry:

```
ls -l DSC_0002.JPG
stat DSC_0002.JPG

find /path/to/myphotos -type f -name 'DSC*JPG' -mtime +400 -mtime -410 -ls
```

And so on...

Comment: That pure Bash approach is instructive (mainly teaching that one should use the proper tool..)  Thanks for sharing all of these, and especially for comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` command to parse output.

In your case `stat` gives output

> 2017-05-05 06:12:37.228033281 -0500

So to get desire output you can use `stat -c %y popen.c | cut -f2 -d' ' | cut -f1 -d'.'`

Refer: [man cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply - for example, the assumption that it's the filesystem inode-change time that's required, and not the EXIF image-capture time.

Comment: The stat command takes the time to create / modify the file on the file system and to create the photo does not matter

Comment: You could parse by using bash: `IFS=" ." read fdate ftime fnanosec foffset < <(stat -c %y myfile)`

Answer (score 1):

Not all images have metadata, but those who have them can get them in the following ways:

```
identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]\n" image.jpg | awk '{print $2}
```

As said Toby Speight:

```
exiftool -time:CreateDate -a -G0:1 -s image.jpg | awk '{print $5}'
```

and

```
jhead image.jpg | awk '/^Date\/Time/{print $4}'
```

I'm sure there are other options, but I did not practice them

Comment: It's works with `identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]" image.JPG` thanks

Comment: Too `identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]\n" DSC_0124.JPG | cut -f2 -d' ' | cut -f1 -d'.' `

Comment: Instead of forking to `awk`, `cut` or any `sed`... You could use [tag:bash] for parsing: `read foo foo date time < <(exiftool -time:CreateDate -s DSC_0002.JPG)`